# ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0 for tensorflow in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

When I try `import tensorflow as tf` in Python in my Ubuntu terminal, I get no errors

But when I use `jupyter notebook` and try `import tensorflow as tf` , I get `ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0`

Trying `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/` doesn't work

Neither does editing `jupyter_notebook_config.py`  at /home/me/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py so it includes at the very top of this file:

```
import os
c = get_config()
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64:usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcudart.so.8.0'
c.Spawner.env.update('LD_LIBRARY_PATH')
```

why is this?

Comment: Is `jupyter` correctly installed for your `python` version? Try starting it with `python -m jupyter notebook` to ensure you're using the correct Python version (no need then to set your LD_LIBRARY_PATH).

Comment: Maybe Cuda 9 is needed however you installed Cuda 8.

Comment: `python -m jupyter notebook` seems to start up `jupyter` fine with no errors

Comment: I'm using Cuda 7.5. Do I need to uninstall it before downloading Cuda 9?

Comment: Your library path in the second paragraph shows Cuda 9.0, the path in the code block indicates Cuda 8.0, and you say you use 7.5. I think there's some discrepancy between those three items.

Comment: If you say Jupyter starts up fine, does it mean it also runs the code in the notebook correctly?

Comment: it runs normal code in the notebook correctly. But I get the error when I just try `import tensorflow as tf` in the notebook